# how to get dynamic data on wordpress from codeigniter?

Tags: wp-query

I made a website with WordPress and Codeigniter.
I create 4 pages on Codeigniter then one more blog page in WordPress.
I get the footer data dynamically on the Codeigniter based site.

I need to take the same footer data dynamically on my WordPress pages.

Comment: yes thats my question

Comment: okey.....well, I have to include footer.php file into wp file but for that I have to give path of footer file.....how??

Answer (score 0):

If your footer file name is `abc.php` inside **Codeigniter** pages and you want to run that file in the **WordPress** directory. In the `footer.php` file in **WordPress** include your `abc.php` file. Otherwise, you can make your own functions to call or manage the content.

```
<?php include 'abc.php'; ?>
```

Comment: well, before include abc.php whether i need to connect mysql with db name??from where I want to retrieve data

Comment: I think you don't need to reconnect db. But give it a try fist without db connection.

Comment: so I just need to mention db name of CI site from where I need to take data dynamically in my WP site

Comment: just include that file no need to add database connection etc.

Comment: bro let me clear you one thing my WP db is diff and my CI db is diff...okey! if I include CI db file in WP db site,, so obviously I have to mention CI db name , as I want to take data from CI into WP..!!